# VB .Remove from String

Tags: vb.net, string, methods

I have to prepare a school project of a Currency Converter in Visual Studio using Basic language. 
I get the value of extange from XE website and it returns a string like "1.23454 GBP' So I need to remove most characters and numbers from it to have it as a Decimal, not String anymore so I can times it later in calculation. 
I've tried to use .Remove anywhere and place it in textBox or Label but it didn't work.

```
Public Class receipt
Private Sub receipt_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim testString As String = "sadasdasd"
    customername.Text = "Name: " + My.Settings.Username
    Label6.Text = "Entered Money: " + My.Settings.inputamount + " " + My.Settings.currency
    Label7.Text = "Converted To: " + My.Settings.outputamount
    Label8.Text = "Charge: 0 (0%)"
    TextBox1.Text = testString.Remove(4, 9)
End Sub
```

End Class

[Screenshot of program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dovU.png)

Can someone help me to get this work?

Comment: It is not clear what do you expect to be shown in your TextBox1 if the input is  '1.23454 GBP' . Could you clarify this point?

Comment: In textBox should show 'sad' but the problem is the method .Remove doesn't work at all. I was trying with the value 1.2454 GBP before but it was the same result which means it didn't work at all. I don't know why I cannot .Remove from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current input of "sadasdasd" and your expected return value then the call to `string.Remove` should be

```
TextBox1.Text = testString.Remove(3)
```

If you look at the MSDN [documentation page of string.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) you could see that the index is zero based so you want to remove anything starting from the fourth character that is at index 3 (keeps 0,1,2, removes from 3)

Also It seems that you think that the Remove second parameter is the end index where the Remove action should stop. But this is wrong, the second parameter is the number of characters to remove so 9 is not correct and probably gives you an ArgumentOutofRange Exception

Comment: Thank you so much, it fixed my problem.